# Can an iOS XCode application reference MonoTouch assemblies?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I'm considering how to best divide the effort between the teams for a new project. We've a Windows C# application services team and a smaller iOS Objective-C team. It's also likely sooner or later an Android application will be required.

A domain layer/api assembly on the device that calls our services and handles synchronising with a local data store is a logical component to write in C# and compile with MonoTouch. Then the Objective-C team references this component. Is that possible?  I've read plenty on MonoTouch referencing C assemblies, but can it work the other way around?

It'd be fantastic to hear of any experiences trying this approach out if it is possible!

Thanks
Aaron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although technically possible, there is no easy way of doing so today.

The best you can do for now is to launch the application from C#, and then, if you want, transfer control to your Objective-C code.   During the C# launch, you can register methods to be called back by the Objective-C code using P/Invoke to call something like:

```
delegate void some_callback_t (int parameter1, int parameter2);

[DllImport ("__Internal")]
void SetCallback (some_callback_t callback);

static void mycallback (int parameter1, int parameter2)
{
    // Here goes your C# logic to be called by C
}
```

Then you call:

```
SetCallback (mycallback);
```

Notice that the mycallback has to be a static method (a limitation of static compilation).   Then your Objective-C code can consume services by implementing something like:

```
 typedef (*callback_t) (int p1, int p2);
 callback_t callback;
 void SetCallback (callback_t cb)
 {
     callback = cb;
 }

 void InvokeCSharp ()
 {
     callback (1, 2);
 }
```

Comment: Hi Miguel, thanks for the prompt response. Is it possible to send back complex DTOs as well? Is special marshalling required? - This doesn't look like something I could convince our iOS guru to use. Thanks

Comment: DTO = data transfer object. In general its just a simple object with properties only, and no behavior, used to send data across different layers.

Comment: Thanks for explaining Eduardo, I've only started using that term in the last year or so at work but it's been used often.

Comment: Yes, you can do that.   Just use the standard P/Invoke rules.   A lot of MonoTouch is built that way, the C# structures are just a 1:1 mapping to the Objective-C ones, so there is zero-copy/marshalling goin on